# WSO2 - log4j configuration to avoid DependencyTracker Messages

Tags: log4j, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 6.5.0.

In **log4j.properties** I've configured these lines pretending to stop seeing the DependencyTracker Messages:

```
log4j.logger.DependencyTracker.name = org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker
log4j.logger.DependencyTracker.level = WARN
```

but on the console, I keep seeing:

> [2020-09-03 17:31:00,003] [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local
> entry : fileExchangeProcessStatus was added to the Synapse
> configuration successfully [2020-09-03 17:31:00,026] [EI-Core]  INFO -
> DependencyTracker Local entry : fileExchangeProcessStatus was removed
> from the Synapse configuration successfully [2020-09-03 17:31:00,026]
> [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry :
> fileExchangeProcessStatus was added to the Synapse configuration
> successfully [2020-09-03 17:32:00,003] [EI-Core]  INFO -
> DependencyTracker Local entry : fileExchangeProcessStatus was removed
> from the Synapse configuration successfully [2020-09-03 17:32:00,004]
> [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry :
> fileExchangeProcessStatus was added to the Synapse configuration
> successfully [2020-09-03 17:32:00,030] [EI-Core]  INFO -
> DependencyTracker Local entry : fileExchangeProcessStatus was removed
> from the Synapse configuration successfully [2020-09-03 17:32:00,031]
> [EI-Core]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry :
> fileExchangeProcessStatus was added to the Synapse configuration
> successfully

How do I configure log4j to avoid these messages of DependencyTracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've added this line to log4j.properties and the message disappear.

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker=ERROR,CARBON_LOGFILE,CARBON_MEMORY
```